# git log --pretty=format windows strange behavior

Tags: json, git, cmd, git-log

I reduce the problem to its lowest terms.
Under linux a git command like this:

```
git log --pretty=format:{"commit":"%H"}
```

gives me a valid json element, so something like:

```
{"commit":"20cafdecc9898113ac6215ae70cd7622dc2cae3b"}
```

under windows I obtain a not-valid json element, because in some way windows seems to remove the double-quotes elements and I obtain:

```
{commit:20cafdecc9898113ac6215ae70cd7622dc2cae3b}
```

Do you know why, or how can I fix it making it work under both os?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I assume that your shell on Linux is NOT a `bash` shell because my `bash` shell on Linux gives me the same output as on Windows - without double-quotes.

The doubles-quotes are special characters for most shells - so you have to protect them either by "escaping" or by "quoting".

```
git log --pretty=format:{\"commit\":\"%H\"}
git log --pretty='format:{"commit":"%H"}'
```

This works for bash on Linux and bash on Windows. I have not tested it with `cmd` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you A.H., you're probably right and I'm sorry I gave incorrect information in my question.
The command I run both on windows and linux is the one with your single quote `git log --pretty='format:{"commit":"%H"}'` but in windows in the command prompt launched with 'cmd' I still obtain the logs without double quotes...
I can add that under windows I have a "correct" output (with double quotes) inside the git-bash.

Comment: I don't know the quoting rule for `cmd`, sorry.

Comment: No problem A.H. thank you!
The command with every single double quote escape seems working but now I have another problem I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044157/git-space-between-pretty-format-placeholders/53044589)

Comment: @David In windows you have to escape the quote symbol! `git log --pretty='format:{"""commit""":"%H"}' -n 10`