# git space between pretty format placeholders

Tags: git, cmd, git-log

For some reason ([this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034425/git-log-pretty-format-windows-strange-behavior)) I will probably have to run a git command like this:

```
git log --pretty=format:{\"author\":\"%aE <%aD>\"}
```

but it doesn't work and I obtain this error information:

> `fatal: ambiguous argument '<%aD>"}': unknown revision or path not in`
>   `the working tree.`

but the same command whithout the space works well:

```
git log --pretty=format:{\"author\":\"%aE<%aD>\"}
```

Do you know how to fix this or how to insert a space "programmatically" with another placeholder?
Thanks!

Comment: In Unix-like shells, the solution would be to use single quotes around the entire format, which would eliminate the need for backslashes before the double quotes as well. If you're using some other shell / command-interpreter, find out what kind of quoting it offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not quoting the argument to `--pretty`, you have to escape the space, like:

```
git log --pretty=format:{\"author\":\"%aE\ <%aD>\"}
```

Otherwise `<%aD>\"}` will be interpreted as next argument.

Edit: Or instead try to quote the whole argument, e.g.

```
git log --pretty="format:{\"author\":\"%aE <%aD>\"}"
```

Edit2: The escape char for `cmd` seems to be `^`, so try:

```
git log --pretty=format:{\"author\":\"%aE^ <%aD>\"}
```

Comment: thank you alfunx, but this isn't working... I obtain again the error `fatal: ambiguous argument '<%aD>"}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: @David Okay, I'm not quite sure how quoting works in `cmd`, I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but it isn't working. I'll keep trying something!

Comment: @David I made yet another edit, I think the escape char for `cmd` is `^`.

Comment: yes! This is correct, I think I'll use one of this solutions! Thank you very much!